# Finding spanning tree with maximum minimum degree

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

Given a connected undirected graph, the problem of finding the spanning tree with the minimum max degree has been well-studied (M. F¨urer, B. Raghvachari, "Approximating the minimum degree spanning tree to within one from the optimal degree", ACM-SIAM Symposium on Discrete Algorithms (SODA), 1992). The problem is NP-hard and an approximation algorithm has been described in the reference.

I am interested in the following problem - given a connected undirected graph G = (V1,V2,E), find the spanning tree with the maximum min degree over all internal nodes (non-leaf nodes). Can someone please tell me if this problem has been studied; is it NP-hard or does there exist a polynomial-time algorithm for solving it? Also, the graph can be considered to be bipartite for convenience.

Comment: This would be better in http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Maybe "maximum min degree of internal node" is more interesting?

Comment: Sry, I realized my mistake; I am editing the problem statement.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in  Evgeny Kluev's comment, the leaves of a (finite) tree have degree 1.  (Else, cycles would exist and the structure would not be a tree.)

If instead you mean to find a spanning tree with a node of maximum degree, from among all possible spanning trees on a connected undirected graph G, then just form a spanning tree whose root R is a node M of G with maximal degree among all the nodes of G, and all neighbors of M are children of R.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like exact cover by 3-sets can be reduced to this problem. Represent the 3-sets by vertices of degree 4, each with 3 edges connecting it to 3 nodes representing its elements in the original problem instance. The additional 4th edge connects all the "3-set" nodes to a single vertex V.

This graph is biparite - every edge is between a "3-set" node and an "element" node (or V). Now this graph has a spanning tree of max min degree = 4 if and only if the original problem has a solution.

Obviously there need to be enough of the 3-sets so that the node V doesn't lower the max min degree of the tree, but this limit doesn't change the NP-hardness of the problem.